# Unhandled runtime error on my server side rendered next.js website when trying to make the header client side rendered

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side-rendering

I created a server side rendered react website with next.js. I wanted to add a simple event listener to header for it to appear-disappear on scroll. In order to do it i have to import useState and useEffect. In order to do it, I have to render the header client side.

I had "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')" trying to make the header render on the client side with writing "use client" on top of my header js file. I tried to debug it by looking through the js files that causing the error but since I have very little experience with node and react, I didn't understand anything. Can someone help me solve this problem? The callstack is as follows:

Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

### Call Stack

#### options.factory

file:///C:/Users/TheUser/Desktop/website_project/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (716:31)

#### _*webpack_require*_

file:///C:/Users/TheUser/Desktop/website_project/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)

#### fn

file:///C:/Users/TheUser/Desktop/website_project/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (371:21)

#### requireModule

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (156:22)

#### initializeModuleChunk

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (1357:0)

#### readChunk

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (1167:0)

#### mountLazyComponent

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (16540:0)

#### beginWork$1

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (18260:0)

#### beginWork

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26647:0)

#### performUnitOfWork

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (25493:0)

#### workLoopConcurrent

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (25479:0)

#### renderRootConcurrent

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (25435:0)

#### performConcurrentWorkOnRoot

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (24288:0)

#### workLoop

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (261:0)

#### flushWork

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (230:0)

#### MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline

node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (534:0)

Comment: can you please share some code?
are you using 'use-client' already for this particular component ?

Comment: ' "use client" //this little piece of code breaks the page.

import React from 'react';

import "./header.css";

const PUBLIC_URL = "";



function Header() { 

  const logoUrl = "/assets/UscLogo.webp"; 



  return (

    <header id="header-element"> 

    </header>

  );

}



export default Header; ' i did not use use client before, it is all ssr. however i want only the header to render serverside so that i can implement a scroll handling code.the page loads very briefly then it throws error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.